# Java API to convert IPv6 from one format to another format

Tags: java, apache, format, ipv6

Could you please let me know if Java has any API to convert IPv6 String from format to another format.

For example - 2002:9876:57AB::1 to 2002:9876:57AB:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001.

Comment: According to the Standards Track _[RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952)_, you should accept all valid IPv6 address representations, but you should only output the canonical format (compressed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have once tried out [this library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/). May be it is what you are looking for.

```
import inet.ipaddr.AddressStringException;
import inet.ipaddr.IPAddress;
import inet.ipaddr.IPAddressString;

public class FoodApp{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws AddressStringException{  
        String ip = "2002:9876:57AB::1";
        String unCompressed = new IPAddressString(ip).toAddress().toFullString();
        System.out.println(unCompressed);
        String compressed = new IPAddressString(unCompressed).toAddress().toCompressedString();
        System.out.println(compressed);
    }
}

//2002:9876:57ab:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
//2002:9876:57ab::1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eritrean.

Comment: I have found one more API:
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.java-ipv6</groupId>
   <artifactId>java-ipv6</artifactId>
   <version>0.16</version>
  </dependency>

Code: IPv6Address.fromString(inputIP).toLongString();